# How to covert byte data to a String or any other comparable type in Lua

Tags: redis, lua

Because of a historical reason, we store  byte data in Redis. There’s  a field which is the version of the data, I want to compare the value of the version  to decide wether to save the coming data. How to achieve this?

Comment: Show us an example of the data and what you're trying to do.

Comment: @lhf to convert such data  `\x00\x00\x01f\xd3d\x80X` to `1541144871000`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this

```
local original = '\x00\x00\x01f\xd3d\x80X'
local param = '\x00\x00\x01f\xd3d\x80W'
local temp1 = ''
local temp2 = ''
for i = 1, #original do
  local c = original:sub(i,i)
  temp1 = temp1.. string.byte(c)
  --    print(string.byte(c))
 end
for i = 1, #param do
  local c = param:sub(i,i)
  temp2 = temp2.. string.byte(c)
  --    print(string.byte(c))
end
if(temp2>temp1) then
    print(1)
else
    print(0)
end
```

Comment: You can replace the loops with `transformed_string = string.gsub(string_to_transform, '.', string.byte)`. But your results will sometimes be incorrect because bytes 1-9 will have one digit, bytes between 10-99 two digits, and bytes between 100 and 255 three. For instance, for both `'\1\100'` and  `'\110\0'`, the modified version will be `'1100'`. Better to use two hex digits per byte: `string.gsub(str, '.', function (char) return ('%02X'):format(string.byte(char) end)`.

Comment: But you might get the same result by using the greater-than operator on the original string. (I guess it depends on the C locale though.)

Comment: @cyclaminist Thank you so much, I love you, buddy. I didn't expect such cases, and your code is much more simple, I tested it using `\x00\x00\x01f\xd3d\x80X` and `\x00\x00n\xd3\x01d\x80X`, it's just perfect.

Comment: Whoops, my code is missing a parenthesis: it should be `string.gsub(str, '.', function (char) return ('%02X'):format(string.byte(char)) end)`. If it worked, you probably figured that out. Glad to help.

Comment: Of course, I added it, and it indicates that you write the code without IDE. You are so good at Lua.